# Mysterious altnames on bridge interfaces

Tags: linux, iproute

I have a bridge interface setup at boot by network manager so I can easily run virtual machines however recently it has been setting weird altnames at boot. I have an `altname U` and an `altname П`. When manually adding a bridge interface with `ip` I only get the `altname П`. When attempting to delete these altnames with `ip l prop d bridge0 altname П` it gives back a `RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`. Is this a bug with `iproute2`? What could be the cause of these weird phantom altnames? I'm on debian sid, kernel 5.6.3.

Full `ip` output:

```
3: bridge0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether ae:e7:a4:3d:19:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
altname U
altname П
```

Output of `ip l | od -c` https://paste.sr.ht/%7Escoopta/bf838c2c031e85db00b5df4774c4e375bec5b3e1

Comment: If you'd give actual examples how the names look like, maybe we could guess. Do you really have trailing `U` or `П`? Because that would be really really strange.

Comment: I put the full output but yes, those are the actual names

Comment: I have added a link to that output https://paste.sr.ht/%7Escoopta/bf838c2c031e85db00b5df4774c4e375bec5b3e1

Comment: Definitely fishy characters. Try this (you need xxd): `(printf '%02x' 0220 0307 034 0206 0327 0125; echo '' ; printf '%02x' 0320 0237 0323 0342 003 0177; echo '') | while read -r alt; do printf '%s' "$alt"| xxd -p -r;echo ''; done | xargs -d '\n' -I{} echo ip link prop del bridge0 altname {}`

Comment: @A.B yes, I realized it depends on the terminal. I use kitty which hides the mangled parts of unicode. Also the name seems to change with each boot. I converted your example to the new mangled altname and it indeed works and successfully removes them. It's really weird however that they're created even when manually making an interface doing `ip l a bridge1 type bridge`

Comment: Obviously there's a bug somewhere: the tool creating them or the kernel. I have a kernel 5.6 and iproute2 5.6.0 but don't have this problem. You could check creating a bridge in an other namespace (ip netns add test + ip netns exec test bash) in case it's an other tool adding the tag later. It shouldn't detect the hidden bridge then

Comment: @A.B hmmmm creating a bridge in the other namespace yields no altname so something definitely seems to be messing with it after the fact. I might spin up a debian VM and see if it happens there and mess with some stuff to try to fix it.

Comment: @A.B so a fresh debian VM exhibits this issue with nothing installed but the base system which was installed using `debootstrap` this is a very weird issue.

Comment: You'll have to figure out which tool (systemd-something, NetworkManager etc.), then time to do a bug report (at Debian) I guess

Comment: Somebody already did: [Debian Bug report logs - 955330](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=955330 "iproute2: corrupted output of "altname"")

Comment: Alright, then I guess that explains everything.